# AJAX not passing data to PHP script?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this code:

```
<form id="login" name="login" class="login-form" action="./" method="post">
      <h2>Log In</h2>
      <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
      <input type="text" id="login-username" placeholder="Full Name" />
      <input type="password" id="login-password" placeholder="Password" />
      <button onclick="submitLogin();">Log In</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(".login").submit(function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
});

function submitLogin() {
    username = $(".login-username").val();
    password = $(".login-password").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        datatype: "string",
        data: {'username' : username, 'password' : password},

.....
```

And this is my PHP script (login.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'config.php';

$uName = $_POST['username'];
$pWord = md5($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT id, username, password, email FROM users WHERE username = '$uName' AND password = '$pWord'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


if($numrows == 1 ) {
    echo 'true';
    $_SESSION['uName'] = $row['username'];
}
else {
    echo 'false';
    }
?>
```

When I try to echo out `$uName` or `$pWord` its empty. Not sure whats going on. Help would be awesome. When I edit a correct username and password to `$uName` and `$pWord` into the PHP.. say: `$uName = kriiv;` and that is a correct username, it echoes out fine. So it just looks like the data is not coming across via the AJAX call.

Comment: Change `(".login-username")` to `("#login-username")` and `(".login-password")` to `("#login-password")` since you're using IDs and not classes.

Comment: Don't wait till your site gets hacked. Someone posted a question earlier about his getting hacked with similar code as yours. Your code is highly prone to SQL injection. Use [**`mysqli_` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: Plus, for password storage use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). MD5 is old and considered broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy these it will work because login-username and login-password are id's not class.

```
username = $("#login-username").val();
password = $("#login-password").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
   username = $(".login-username").val();
   password = $(".login-password").val();
```

to

```
   username = $("#login-username").val();
   password = $("#login-password").val();
```

`.` is used to get element having class `#` is used for having id , your element having id not class